# Batch file Error : "Files was unexpected at this time."

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am getting the below error when I pass `path` as my 2nd argument. It looks like problem is with the space.

`Files was unexpected at this time`

I am executing the batch file with following parameters

`services.cmd 2 "C:\Program Files (x86)\folder\Folder\folder\Bin" corp\acct password`

CODE:

```
@echo off

if "%1" == "" goto PARAMS
if "%2" == "" goto PARAMS
if "%3" == "" goto PARAMS
if "%4" == "" goto PARAMS


sc create "<service name>"%1 binpath= "\%2\xxx.exe\" \"xxx.exe.config\""
rem sc config "<service name>"%1 displayname= "<display name>"%1 obj= %3 password= %4 start= auto description= "Runs the service."


goto END

:PARAMS

echo Usage CreateServices.cmd binfoldername binfolderpath username password

:END
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code of the batch file and the value of the path you pass?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot escape quotes within a quoted string. Use `%~2` to get rid of the unwanted quotes from a parameter.

Try the following:

```
sc create "<service name>%~1" binpath= "%~2\xxx.exe" "xxx.exe.config"
```

Comment: I changed %2 to %~2 i.e

sc create "<servicename>"%1 binpath= "\~%2 \"xxx.exe.config\""

but still getting the error:

Files was unexpected at this time

when i pass services.cmd 2 "C:\Program\folder\Folder\folder\Bin" corp\acct password it works

Looks like batch file is not accept it as an argument

Comment: @user1838411 - Try the line as I have it in my answer. Also, implement the changes shown in foxidrive's answer.

Answer (score 3):

As well as Dave's comment, you need tildas in these lines

```
if "%~1" == "" goto PARAMS
if "%~2" == "" goto PARAMS
if "%~3" == "" goto PARAMS
if "%~4" == "" goto PARAMS
```

But all you need to check for all four parameters (if all 4 are required) is this:

```
if "%~4" == "" goto PARAMS
```

Answer (score 0):

I Just changed to useing `'` instead of `"` ,

```
if NOT '%1' == '' SET var1=%1
if NOT '%2' == '' SET var2=%2
if NOT '%3' == '' SET var3=%3
```

Ang got it working without the error, not sure if related to parameter expansion , as I am not using parenthesis